# Installing i3wm on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, i3-wm

I've been trying to install i3wm on Ubuntu 16.04LTS [using](https://i3wm.org/docs/repositories.html).

The advice I've seen online is always along the lines of

```
sudo apt install i3wm
```

but the official 16.04 package only goes to version 4.11 of i3. I've tried installing from source but that gives tons of dependency erros, wherein some of the dependencies don't seem to really exist, definitely not with the same name, in 16.04.

I've also tried with the repository maintained by sur5r described on [link](https://i3wm.org/docs/repositories.html) but that results with the following error:

```
E: The repository 'http://debian.sur5r.net/i3 $(grep Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

I can't find much helpful info on how to proceed? Is it worth the time attempting to get a version newer than 4.11 on ubuntu 16.04. Would it be possible to pull a more up-to-date package from [here](https://pkgs.org/download/i3-wm) or is that going to be a dependency hell as well.

Btw I am forced to use 16.04 for other dependency reasons to upgrading to 18.04 will not be an option.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install i3-wm`. It seems from here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/i3-wm is should be available in 16.04.

Comment: That's only for 18.10 or whatever the newest is, if you look at 16.04(Xenial-Xerus) then it's still running 4.11 on the official repositories. I'm not entirely sure what upstreaming does, but I'll look into that, that may be a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified [official method](https://i3wm.org/docs/repositories.html) as following:

```
/usr/lib/apt/apt-helper download-file http://debian.sur5r.net/i3/pool/main/s/sur5r-keyring/sur5r-keyring_2019.02.01_all.deb keyring.deb SHA256:176af52de1a976f103f9809920d80d02411ac5e763f695327de9fa6aff23f416
sudo dpkg -i keyring.deb

sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://debian.sur5r.net/i3/ xenial universe"
sudo apt update
sudo apt install i3
```

and I get 4.16.1 installed:

> ```
> $ i3 --version
> i3 version 4.16.1 (2019-01-27) © 2009 Michael Stapelberg and contributors
> ```

you can select this session on login screen (usually LighDM or GDM).

Comment: Calling `sudo apt update` returns the same error: `The repository 'http://debian.sur5r.net/i3 $(grep Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.`

Comment: Then you should find this problematic line in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and remove it. Then follow my answer.